# Creating new CSV with selected columns from another

Tags: python, csv, output

I'm trying to create a script that selects some columns from a CSV file and saves them into another one (ideally specifying the column header).
This is the query I'm starting from, which will copy all columns. How to change that to copy just a selection of them?

```html
# importing openpyxl module
import openpyxl as xl;
  
# opening the source excel file
filename ="C:\\Users\\...\\input.clv"
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]
  
# opening the destination excel file 
filename1 ="C:\\Users\\...\\output.clv"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1)
ws2 = wb2.active
  
# calculate total number of rows and 
# columns in source excel file
mr = ws1.max_row
mc = ws1.max_column
  
# copying the cell values from source 
# excel file to destination excel file
for i in range (1, mr + 1):
    for j in range (1, mc + 1):
        # reading cell value from source excel file
        c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j)
  
        # writing the read value to destination excel file
        ws2.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value
  
# saving the destination excel file
wb2.save(str(filename1))
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there any reason you're using openpyxl? If you're just working with CSV files, you can achieve this using standard Python text file reading/writing as CSV files are plaintext files.

Comment: are you okay with CSV library? openpyxl is a proprietary format and has very little support. CSV is good and is compatible with microsoft excel too

Answer (score 0):

This is how I might do it using Python file reading/writing.

```
def readCsv(fileName):
  data = []
  myFile = open(fileName, "r")
  for line in myFile:
    lineList = line.split(",")
    lineList[len(lineList)-1] = lineList[len(lineList) - 1].replace("\n", "")
    data.append(lineList)
  myFile.close()
  return data

def writeCsv(data):
  dataString = ""
  for line in data:
    dataString =dataString + ','.join(line)+"\n"
  myNewFile = open("output.csv", "w")
  myNewFile.write(dataString)
  myNewFile.close()

data = readCsv("yourCsv.csv")
# Remove the data you don't need
writeCsv(dataAfterRemovingColumns)
```

My `readCsv` function produces a 2D List where each item is a list of the data in one row of the CSV file. So, where I have commented `# Remove the data you don't need` you would iterate through the 2D list, removing the item from each row that makes up part of the column you want to delete. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your purpose of saving some columns from a csv file to another, you can utilize pandas library as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

def save_csv(df, path, cols):
    df[cols].to_csv(path, index=False)

with open('path/to/csv', r) as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)

# Assuming you want to save columns colA and colB
save_csv(df, path/to/dest/csv, ['colA', 'colB'])
```

You can also use csv DictReader, DictWriter as another approach which is longer in code, but faster in time (based on my timing):

```
import csv

def use_csv():
    def new_dict(d, cols):
        new_dict = {}
        for col in cols:
            new_dict[col] = d[col]
        return new_dict

    with open('path/to/csv', 'r') as f:
        df = csv.DictReader(f)

        with open('path/to/dest/csv', 'w') as csvfile:
            fieldnames = ['colA', 'colB']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

            writer.writeheader()
            for row in df:
                data = new_dict(row, fieldnames)
                writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: Using the first one I get an error:
'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'save_csv'

With the second one nothing happens . Any reason why?

Comment: sorry, there is mistake of redundant `df.save_csv`, it should be `save_csv` (without `df.`). I have updated it above. Regarding the 2nd solution, have you checked the destination file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) from stdlib:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv

inputCsvFilePath  = 'input.csv'
outputCsvFilePath = 'output.csv'

inputCsvColumnNumbers  = [1,3,5]
outputCsvColumnHeaders = ['one', 'three', 'five']

# reading/writing row by row (high IO, low memory):
with open(inputCsvFilePath) as inputCsv:
    inputCsvReader = csv.reader(inputCsv)

    with open(outputCsvFilePath, 'w') as outputCsv:
        outputCsvWriter = csv.writer(outputCsv)

        # write custom csv header:
        outputCsvWriter.writerow(outputCsvColumnHeaders)
        # skip input file header:
        inputCsvReader.__next__()

        for inputRow in inputCsvReader:
            outputCsvWriter.writerow( [inputRow[i] for i in inputCsvColumnNumbers] )
```

Personally, I'd use sqlite for that:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

sqlite3 <<EOF
-- input:
.separator ',' "\n"

.import 'input.csv' inputData


-- output:
.mode csv
.header on
.once 'output.csv'

select
  user_id  as "one"
, login_id as "three"
, password as "five"
from inputData
;
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this shorter way using DictReader & DictWriter:

```
import csv
with open('original.csv', newline='') as originalfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(originalfile)
    
    with open('new.csv', 'w', newline='') as newfile:
        fieldnames = ['asset_id', 'treatments']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(newfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()

        for row in reader:   
            writer.writerow({'asset_id':row['Asset ID'], 'treatments':row['Treatments Identified']})
```